# How can we change the session timeout or the max sessions per user in a Spring Boot application AT RUNTIME?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

To configure this at boot-up time we can either set it in the HttpSecurity object or in application.yml. But how can we do this at dynamically at run-time? i.e. in response to a user prompt after the system has started up and is already serving requests and has logged-in users.

Comment: Is restarting Spring Boot and externalizing configuration an option? Or you don't want to restart the service? With an external configuration you can import the properties and with a restart load the new configuration.

Comment: No, I don't want to force all users out and then ask them to log in again.